# How to count number of stores per company per region?

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have two layers. One point layer and a Polygon layer. 
It is simple to count the points in the polygon layer by the "points in polygon" function. But I also need some more information of the point layer in the polygon layer.

For example:

The point layer includes information of the company name (and some more) of every point.

--> I need the number of Points in the polygon layer but also some information about how many stores of company XYZ are in the polygon

I tried my luck with the "select by location" function but this works just the other way round (I can create a point layer with all necessary information but not a polygon layer because the function only uses the "attributes of the first exact object".

The other possibility of chosing a summarization is not in my interest because I need to keep all information - anyway it does not work because my column names will be to long after creating it.

I will add a screenshot to better explain my problems (it is the german version and I am actually working in France so please try to overlook my faults ;)

[image: point and polygone attribute tables]

Comment: Have a look at: [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68546/want-to-display-count-of-records-within-a-given-area-electoral-district/68555#68555) for summing a value from a points layer for each polygon in a polygon layer.

Comment: Install the MMQGIS plugin and use the 'spatial join' tool

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to add to each point the information about which region it is in, eg. using the [Add polygon attributes to points](http://anitagraser.com/2013/10/02/add-polygon-attributes-to-points-vs-join-attributes-by-location/) tool. Then you can use [Group Stats](http://anitagraser.com/2013/02/02/group-stats-tutorial/)' pivot table functionality to count the number of points per company per region. You would have region IDs in the rows, company names in the columns, and the count function in value:

[image]